# Is Bubble Sort the slowest sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, speed

Is bubble sort the least Big-O efficient? If the answer is no, then what is the least efficient sorting algorithm?

Comment: As long as your algorithm terminates, you can always make a slower algorithm (by a constant factor, or asymptotically) by adding redundant work. To make the algorithm asymptotically (big O) slower, the redundant work has to grow faster (as the data grows) than the growth of the original algorithm.

Comment: @Steve314, the redundant work should be reasonable.

Comment: The fact is that giving a precise definition of "reasonable", and so making this question answerable at all, would be a rather difficult task. By far harder than answering most questions on SO.

Comment: @Andrea: I am satisfied with CoolBeans' answer.

Comment: This is fine. If the question is just "What are some fun ways to sort slowly?", CoolBeans' is a perfectly good answer. On the other hand, it may have been the case that you thought that your question admitted a rigorous answer, like the similar-sounding, but actually very different, question "What is the **fastest** way to sort an array?". In this case, it would have been good to clarify that looking for the slowest algorithm is an ill-posed problem.

Comment: Bubble Sort is a very slow bathing algorithm for n (number of babies) > 1.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2609857/827263) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1185/ Stacksort is definitely the slowest (check the hovertext)

Comment: [Why this is not a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474318/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-sleep-sort). If you're trying to find, as you say, "the least efficient sorting algorithm" you'd have to account for all of the solutions that are intentionally inefficient. Even then, it's a matter of opinion because the number of possible solutions is endless.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I vote for [BogoSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) to be the worst if you are comparing based on worst case performance only!

Visit this wiki [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) to get a general idea of run time comparisons of different sorts. The sort performance is always highly dependent on your data and scenario. It's hard to say one to be the worst always.

Comment: @xport - Who says developers are just a bunch of nerds - we have our sense of humor too ;-).

Comment: :D +1 for knowing this even exists! Who would have known?!!

Comment: @abhiii5459 - Never even think about using it though ;)

Comment: Of course,of course.. O(∞)?! No,thank you :D

Comment: Even Mr. Obama did not know this algorithm. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4RRi_ntQc8

Comment: That's nothing..ERIC SHMIDT didn't know about Bogosort!!! Same video :D

Comment: @xport good one. I am surprised that President Obama even heard of bubble sort.

Comment: BogoBogoSort is even better. Apparently it has a complexity of `O(N!^n)` or similar. Looky here: http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/bogobogosort.html

Comment: It's not so bad, it may be optimal on a quantum computer =P

Comment: If BogoSort is like shuffle the whole deck if the stick isn't of right number - you have a reasonable algorithm for hazard games. It's not just about cpu cycles.

Comment: Unfortunately implementing a BogoSort that works correctly for all sizes of lists is practically impossible.

Comment: To be fair, if you got REALLY luck, BogoSort could theoretically sort your list in a single step and be VERY fast.

Answer (score 19):

Short of the intentionally perverse, there is still one that's slower than bubble sort, but has a real reason to exist (sort of, anyway). Knuth V3 (in one of the exercises) shows an algorithm optimized to minimize code size. It does produce extremely small code -- at the oh-so-minor expense of O(N<sup>3</sup>) complexity.

Although the chances of actually encountering it with modern hardware are nonexistent, it's also worth mentioning that under precisely the correct set of circumstances Bubble sort isn't really such a terrible algorithm at all -- rather the contrary, within the exactly correct set of constraints on the hardware it's provably not only as good as anything else, but asymptotically approaches the best performance of any possible algorithm.

In fact, that proof appears to be the primary reason it became reasonably widely known -- it's virtually the first algorithm for which any such formal proof was ever published. OTOH, that's almost lost in the mists of time, and most of the people who teach it have no idea why it originally became known. Instead, as far as I can tell, people teach it solely because they learned it, and for some reason think it's important for the next generation to learn about it even though the reason for its existence disappeared long before most of them were born.

If you are going to include intentionally perverse algorithms, then the bogobogosort is *much* worse than the plain bogosort. A plain bogosort has a complexity of approximately O(N * N!). The bogobogosort has a complexity of approximately O(N<sup>N-k</sup>). To put this in perspective, bogosort can sort 10 items in a matter of only a few minutes (or so). The number of operations needed for a bogobogosort grow so fast that to the best of my knowledge, the largest number of items anybody has ever sorted with it is 6 (attempts have been made at 7, but, at least to my knowledge, all such attempts have been terminated before completion (though, admittedly, that's usually after only a day or two).

Comment: +1 for several points, but I don't see how bubble sort can be considered asymptotically as fast as mergesort or heapsort, both of which are worst case O(n log n), whereas bubblesort is worst case O(n^2). In practical performance, randomized quicksort is often the real winner, despite also being O(n^2) worst case, but that's not really about asymptotic performance. True, quicksorts is O(n log n) expected, but so are some other sorts - the real-world performance gains relative to e.g. heapsort are due to cache-friendliness and simplicity.

Comment: @Steve314: The restriction is basically a machine with drum memory that restricts you to access to two adjacent items at a time, with the window constantly moving in one direction (and when you reach the end, you can re-start at the beginning reasonably cheaply, but random access is *really* expensive). Heapsort basically requires random access. Mergesort is fine with sequential access, but requires *non*-adjacent sequences.

Comment: @Jerry - interesting restriction.

Comment: @Steve314: They are, a bit. Apparently it was originally for (or at least based on) real hardware though.

Comment: Interesting. I always just sorta figured that bubblesort was so well known because it's so intuitive. If I had to write a sorting algorithm and I had no prior knowledge of sorting algorithms and the theory behind them, my first attempt would probably look a whole lot like bubblesort.

Comment: @Mason: I can see people inventing either insertion or selection sort, and when they figured out the problem with O(N*N) algorithms, probably merge sort. Bubble sort strikes as *much* less intuitive than any of the above.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I think a catchy name has a lot to do with popularity of the method: a sort by any other name would not smell as sweet :)

Comment: In the old days before we had sort routines in our libraries bubble sort had the advantage of being very easy to implement.  There are times it's actually a reasonable solution--when n has a very low hard limit.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: ...but selection sort and insertion sort as just as easy to implement (arguably even a bit easier) and almost always faster (and, I'm pretty sure, never slower).

Answer (score 7):

The speed of any particular sorting algorithm depends on a few different factors such as input order and key distribution. In many cases bubble sort is pretty slow, but there are some conditions under which it's very fast.

There's a great sorting algorithm comparison animation at this site:

http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: +1 for the link, unfortunately my response time is so slow to determine which one finishes first.

Answer (score 3):

Bozo sort is O(n!)! It is done by randomly picking two elements swapping them and checking whether the list is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your data is almost sorted already, and that only a few elements are out of place, bubble sort becomes about O(c*N) time, where c is the number of out of place elements. In that instance it will actually be faster than most other sorts. Bad worst case, good best case.

Comment: That's true of cocktail sort, but not bubble sort.  Bubble sort only runs in one direction, so one out of place element is potentially enough to make it run in O(n^2).

Comment: If you only have 1 out of place element, bubble sort will put it in place in O(n) time.

Comment: That is incorrect.  For example, suppose your list of n elements was almost sorted, with only one out of place element.  Specifically, with the first element incorrectly placed at the end.  Then, there will be O(n) iterations of bubble sort, each of which will read the entire n elements of the list, resulting in O(n^2) time.  Iteration 0: `2,3,4,...,n-1,n,1`, Iteration 1: `2,3,4,...,n-1,1,n`, Iteration 2: `2,3,4,...,1,n-1,n`, etc.  Cocktail sort, on the other hand, would only require one iteration, and thus is O(n).

Comment: Ah, I understand your point now that I've read up on it. I imagined an intelligent version of bubble sort to be bidirectional, and that such a thing would still be called bubble sort, so thank you for clarifying that such an optimization has a different name.